# Making HTTPS Request and opening SSL socket in JAVA

Tags: ssl, https, javafx

I am trying to build a login page. For that, I want to open a SSL  socket and make a HTTPS request,but  I'm getting Unknown Host Exception in the line

```java
SSLSocket skt = (SSLSocket)sslsf.createSocket("https://31.21.18.222/room_info/x.txt" , 443);
```

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Also, I've turned off host verification because it wont be needed in my program.

```
`public void clickLogin() throws IOException, CertificateException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
            
                                       
            URL url = new URL ("https://31.21.18.222/room_info/x.txt");
            HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            keyStore.load(null);        //Make an empty store
            InputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/Documents and Settings/user/Desktop/PK/localhost.crt"); 
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            while (bis.available() > 0) {
                java.security.cert.Certificate cert = cf.generateCertificate(bis);
                keyStore.setCertificateEntry("localhost", cert);
            }
            
            // write code for turning off client verification
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
            tmf.init(keyStore);
            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers() , null);
            Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
            SSLSocketFactory sslsf = context.getSocketFactory();
            SSLSocket skt = (SSLSocket)sslsf.createSocket("https://31.21.18.222/room_info/x.txt" , 443);
            skt.setUseClientMode(true);
            SSLSession s = skt.getSession(); // handshake implicitly done
            skt.setKeepAlive(true);
            
             
            connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        
        // Host name verification off
            connection.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier()  
            {        
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session)  
                {  
                    return true;  
                }  
            });  `
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use both an `HttpsUrlConnection` and an `SSLSocket` directly, by the way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to open a socket with `createSocket`, you need to use the host name (or IP address), not the full URL:

```
example : sslsf.createSocket("31.21.18.222" , 443);
```

In addition:

- Don't use `Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider())` (it's there by default).
- It's probably better to use `TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm())` instead of `X.509`, especially because the default algorithm for the TMF is `PKIX`, not `X.509`.
- `createSocket` will verify the certificate against the trust anchors, but won't check the host name (which is also required to prevent MITM attacks). For this, it's also generally better to use a host name instead of an IP address.

Comment: +1 for the nice explanation. Joe Roth, it is great if you can reward this by accepting if this is helps you. I bet it does :)